# What is this diode?

Tags: diodes, components, identification

I found this set of diodes in a (possibly labelled) anti-static bag, but have since lots the bag. The marking on the diode appear to be

```
]::  244
R    2 0
```

The `::` is more of subdivided rectangle, with less space between parts:

[image]

Is the `]::` a logo of some semiconductor manufacturer?

What is this part? I think it might be a 200V zener, but I don't trust my memory.

Answer (score 2):

That is a Diodes Inc symbol, I don't think they use it any more.

Here is an old datasheet that uses it:
http://datasheet.octopart.com/B540C-13-F-Diodes-Inc.-datasheet-10028006.pdf

That should help narrow it down, but I didn't find anything on their web site searching for the part markings you see. You may be able to reach out to a Field Applications Engineer at Diodes Inc to get a better identification.

Edit: From their site it looks like all of their currently offered Zeners are SMT, but depending where you got the part it might be obsolete, so could still be a 200V zener as you think.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a BA244 pin diode, which are normally glass.
logo not recognized.